# How to get dial number in iOS using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

In my iOS application i want to fetch dial number,receive call number. i searched on internet and i found out that some iOS device folder is accessible and some not. it is possible to read dial and receive call number from iOS Device.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about it. You probably can't as you would have to ask permission to the user to access the recent numbers dialed and received calls. May be it is possible with jailbroken devices.